# WebView as ListView rows not scrolling properly

Tags: android, webview, scroll, textview

I'm trying to make a `ListView` that is supposed to act something like what the stock messaging app or GTalk does. It shows a conversation between two people. The `WebView` is responsible for showing the HTML text of the conversation **INCLUDING several gif animations (smileys -- which a `TextView` is incapable of showing)**  Obviously when a new message arrives, the list has to scroll all the way to the bottom (I'm using `listview.setSelection(...)` for that)
Now if the `WebView`'s height is longer than normal, the `ListView` messes up and scrolls to an item close to the end of the list and not the last item. Like I said, I think the list has problem calculating the height of it's children. (Have already disabled `smoothScroll` on the `ListView`as the documentation mentions.

the layout file used as rows in the `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="#f7f7f7">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFriendAvatarChat"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/friendMessageWebView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I haven't got any useful answer for [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434208/android-show-gif-animations-smileys-inline-with-text) or [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561866/android-prevent-unwanted-flicker-due-to-innate-webview-behavior) and I'm resorting to one last solution that comes to mind which is a nasty one in deed and then I'm kissing Android goodbye!  (As you can guess, I'm already fed up with Android hindering every aspect of development.)

The solution there is using `WebView` as `ListView` rows to show what I want. The problem is that if the content of the `WebView` is say, 3 lines, then the ListView goes crazy and does not scroll to the bottom of the list properly. My guess is that the it fails to calculate the height of each child row and mistakenly navigates to the middle of the list instead of bottom of it.

I have already read too many similar questions like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456554/listview-with-webview) and I have not got a good response...

Comment: More related to your previous questions; but I assume you didn't get your animations working/desired results with an AnimationDrawable? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Comment: @Jave I have already tried tampering with that! The problem is, how can I inline that with text??

Comment: I have never had the need to try it myself, but you can use compoundDrawables in the textview. This might not be what you want as you can't really put the images/smileys in the text, only next to it. Then I think you would be better of creating your own view/viewGroup that is able to handle multiple textsegments/drawables. An interesting problem to say the least.

Comment: @Jave Now that's why I say that I'm fed up with Android...If it was in Windows Mobile, I just knew how to handle it without painful manipulation of existing controls.  In the case of Android, anybody can create an open-ended framework and assert that the developers have the freedom to do what they want!!! Shame on Google for leaving our hands tied like this... Thanks for the response anyway!

Comment: I don't share your point of view even though I see what you're getting at. I really like developing for android. But then again, I haven't tried any of the other platforms. Good luck with your project anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is thathe webview does not have a size when it is created and measured   the height is valid onlyafter the webview has fished loading and rendering the content which is usually too late for the listview to calculate the size.
 Did you consider fixing a height to the layout. 
How about not using a listview instead one big webview?

Comment: I had my doubts regarding this. The thing is that I can't use fixed height for the WebView as is going to show the content of a message and the length of the message is not known ahead of time and I don't want scroll bars to appear on the WebView! Like I in the other question, WebView has it's own problems (not scrolling to the bottom of the page properly)

Comment: @M2X did you find any solution regarding this problem? i am facing the same problem

Comment: @AkhileshSk No unfortunately I didn't... I ended up taking a different route of forgetting about GIF animations and displaying static images instead!

Comment: @M2X i have found out a solution that adding all the webview items in scrollview rather than adding in listview and it will definately solve your problem.Prakash Nadar was quite correct about his conclusion